# ObjectMapper.readTree does not throw IOException on Invalid input

Tags: java, jackson, jackson-databind

I am using Jackson databind `2.9.10`. According to the documentation it states:

> If a parsing problem occurs (invalid JSON), JsonParseException will be thrown

See: [ObjectMapper.readTree](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.9.10/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#readTree-java.io.InputStream-)

I have the following test:

```
    // Given
    String invalidJson = new POJONode("}{").toString();
    final InputStream mockInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(invalidJson.getBytes());

    // When
    myLambda.handleRequest(mockInputStream, mockOutputStream, mockContext);

    // Then
    Expect some stuff to happen in the catch JsonProcessingException bit
```

However, `readTree` converts it into a `TextNode` and doesn't throw an exception...

Debug:
[image]

How can I configure ObjectMapper to throw on an invalid input?

Comment: Looks like your JSON contains a JSON String with the value `"}{"`, nothing wrong with that. Please provide a [mcve] otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you print `invalidJson` variable you will see `"}{"` which is actually a valid `JSON` acordding to [json.org](https://www.json.org/). You can also confirm that using some web tools like [jsonformatter](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/). Parser will throw exception when you directly set `invalidJson` variable to this string:

```
String invalidJson = "}{";
```

You should see:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected close marker '}': expected ']' (for root starting at [Source: (String)"}{"; line: 1, column: 0])
 at [Source: (String)"}{"; line: 1, column: 2]
```

Comment: It seems that if I am wrapping my string in a node, i.e. `new POJONode("}{");` and then passing it to the objectmapper, it will become a textnode, but passing it directly as a string without wrapping in an object will result in `JsonParseException`

Comment: @px06, yes, because `POJONode` wraps text in quote chars: `"`. So, `}{` becomes `"}{"`. `}{` is not valid `JSON` but `"}{"` is a valid `JSON`